# How to interpret the Confusion Matrix in Python for 2 classes

Tags: scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am implementing a machine learning model in Python which predicts success or failure. I have created a dummy variable which is 1 when there is success and 0 when there is a failure. I understand the concept of confusion matrix but I have found some online where the TPs and TNs are on opposite sides of the matrix. I would like to know how to interpret the results for my variables. Is the top-left corner of the matrix predicting True Positive? If so would that translate to the amount of successes being predicted correctly or the amount of failures being predicted correctly?

[image]

Does the matrix match the diagram below and if so how?

[image]

Ideally, please describe each corner of the confusion matrix in the context where I have success as 1 and failure as 0.

Comment: Rows of the confusion matrix correspond to true classes and columns correspond to predicted classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html

Since you haven't specified the third parameter for `labels` in `confusion_matrix`, the labels in `y_test_res` will be used in sorted order, i.e. in this case `0` then `1`. The row labels represent actual y, and column labels represent predicted y.

So the top-left corner is showing the number of failure observations, i.e. the actual y was `0` and was predicted `0`, i.e. true negatives.  The bottom-right corner is showing true positives, i.e. the actual y was `1` and was predicted `0`.

The top-right corner would be actual y = 0 and predicted y = 1, i.e. false positive.

Using the [confusion matrix plot](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix) would prettify things a little.

```
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix
plot_confusion_matrix(forest, X_test, y_test)  
print(plt.show())
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation.

Unfortunately, since I am quite new this world, the scikit learn documentation is still confusing. Would it be possible to add the labels and perhaps plot it or something to clear things out? I am confused about the bottom right part of TP. I thought TP is when it predicted correctly. In your context if the actual was 1 and predicted is 0 then TP does not make sense to me.

Comment: How about using the `plot_confusion_matrix` function?  That might be more intuitive. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes, if you could show me how to plot it, that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of binary classification where classes are 0 and 1 and according to the [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) :

- 1st row is for class 0
- 2nd row is for class 1
- 1st column is for predicted class 0
- 2nd column is for predicted class 1

Coefficient (0, 0) is the True Negative count (TN).
Coefficient (0, 1) is the False Positive count (FP).
Coefficient (1, 0) is the False Negative count (FN).
Coefficient (1, 1) is the True Positive count (TP).

Comment: Thank you @Ismael EL ATIFI

So according to you, the top left would be TN and the bottom right would be TP?

Basically the reverse of the image I have posted right?

Comment: Yes. It is exact.